# Azure DevOps release error - remotedebuggingversion, bad request

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, pipeline

I'm trying to track down why this release is failing.  It is with the Azure Resource Group deployment and has worked until a week ago.  The error seems random and the variables appear in 2 of our nested template files, function.json and webApp.json.  The original value was null and I changed these values to "VS2012" and "VS2017" without success.  I have also tried changing the remoteDebuggingEnabled from false to true without success. The ARM Templates deploy fine when I deploy through Visual Studio but errors with Azure DevOps.  The only change was made to the previous task in the Azure File Copy task prior to this task where the version was changed from the "Preview" version 2.* to 1.*

Any ideas?  Do I need to provide more information?

The part of the template is under
 "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",

```
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1471124Z ##[section]Starting: Create or Update Azure Infrastructure
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1477792Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1477917Z Task         : Azure Resource Group Deployment
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1478008Z Description  : Deploy an Azure resource manager (ARM) template to a resource group. You can also start, stop, delete, deallocate all Virtual Machines (VM) in a resource group
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1478131Z Version      : 2.141.1
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1478287Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1478360Z Help         : [More Information](https://aka.ms/argtaskreadme)
2018-11-13T02:54:45.1478455Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-13T02:54:45.5851577Z Checking if the following resource group exists: uiis-dev-rg.
2018-11-13T02:54:45.8038374Z Resource group exists: true.
2018-11-13T02:54:45.8040134Z Creating deployment parameters.
2018-11-13T02:54:45.8110536Z The detected encoding for file 'D:\a\r1\a\UIIS-CI\drop\azureDeploy.json' is 'utf-8'
2018-11-13T02:54:45.8268289Z Starting Deployment.
2018-11-13T02:58:06.2894763Z There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.
2018-11-13T02:58:06.2896043Z ##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.
2018-11-13T02:58:06.2896936Z ##[error]Details:
2018-11-13T02:58:06.2898051Z ##[error]Conflict: {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "DeploymentFailed",
        "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",
        "details": [
          {
            "code": "BadRequest",
            "message": "{\r\n  \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"The parameter remoteDebuggingVersion has an invalid value.\",\r\n  \"Target\": null,\r\n  \"Details\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"Message\": \"The parameter remoteDebuggingVersion has an invalid value.\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"Code\": \"BadRequest\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"ErrorEntity\": {\r\n        \"ExtendedCode\": \"01007\",\r\n        \"MessageTemplate\": \"The parameter {0} has an invalid value.\",\r\n        \"Parameters\": [\r\n          \"remoteDebuggingVersion\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"Code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n        \"Message\": \"The parameter remoteDebuggingVersion has an invalid value.\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n}"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
} undefined
2018-11-13T02:58:06.2899605Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
2018-11-13T02:58:06.2972216Z ##[section]Finishing: Create or Update Azure Infrastructure
```

Comment: can you show the relevant part of the template? also, have you seen this example: https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/master/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by removing every remoteDebbugingVersion entry.
I hope this helps